# How to replace data in pandas by using values in dict?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, replace, series

I have a series which contains several numbers. I want to replace them to other string type data by using dictionary values. But I don't know how to do that...

```
GDP_group['GdpForYearPer$1M'].head(5)
```

> 0    46.919625 
> 1    47.515189 
> 2    47.737955 
> 3    54.832578 
> 4    56.338028 
> 5    63.101272 \

This is the dict that I made to replace data.

```
range_GDP = {'$0 ~ $100M': np.arange(0,100), '$100M ~ $1B': np.arange(100.0000001,1000), '$1B ~ $10B': np.arange(1000.000001, 10000), '$10B ~ $100B': np.arange(10000.000001, 100000),
        '$100B ~ $1T': np.arange(100000.000001, 1000000), '$1T ~': np.arange(1000000.000001, 20000000)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut` to segment your data in ranges and apply labels.

(re)generate dummy data sampled uniformly in log space:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
GdpForYearPer1M = pd.Series(10**np.random.randint(0, 8, 100))

"""
0           1
1        1000
2         100
3          10
4         100
       ...
95    1000000
96        100
97     100000
98      10000
99         10
"""
```

solution:

```
# generate "cuts" (bins) and associated labels from `range_GDP`.    

cut_data = [(np.min(v), k) for k, v in range_GDP.items()]
bins, labels = zip(*cut_data)

# bins required to have one more value than labels
bins = list(bins) + [np.inf]
pd.cut(GdpForYearPer1M, bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

output:

```
0       $0 ~ $100M
1      $100M ~ $1B
2       $0 ~ $100M
3       $0 ~ $100M
4       $0 ~ $100M
          ...
95     $100B ~ $1T
96      $0 ~ $100M
97    $10B ~ $100B
98      $1B ~ $10B
99      $0 ~ $100M
Length: 100, dtype: category
Categories (6, object): [$0 ~ $100M < $100M ~ $1B < $1B ~ $10B < $10B ~ $100B < $100B ~ $1T < $1T ~]
```